# Dynamic header position dependent on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I'm working on a site in angular for a client (so it can be a single page site), and he'd like for the header bar to be at the bottom of the page when the user is on the home page, or `/`, and on the top otherwise. In addition, the header would slide up when navigating away from `/` and back down when navigating TO `/`. Here's an attempt at an ASCII illustration.

```
+--------------------+            +--------------------+
|                    |            |     Header/nav     |
|    Basic home      |            +--------------------+
|       page         |            |         ^          |
|                    |            |         |          |
+--------------------+            |                    |
|    Header/nav      | click out->|   (new content)    |
+--------------------+            +--------------------+
```

I'm fairly experienced with angular but can't seem to get a good footing on how to do this. Is JQuery the answer?

Comment: Can you just put a class on the home page body and apply CSS?

Comment: That's what I have happening now. I can have the header change position based on URL, however I'm stuck on getting it to animate on page change.

Comment: I guess I don't understand. Is it a one-page site now? Or are you trying to get animations on page load?

Comment: It's one page now. When you arrive at the home page, the header is on the bottom. When you click on a link to any other page, the header jumps to the top and the page content is loaded. I want to be able to animate the header movement that happens when you move to a new page, or back to the home page. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AngularJS, but this sounds like something easily handled with jQuery. Check the height of the home page wrapper element and check window scroll to see if it's less than that. Do your animation based on that.